# Change PowerPoint slide size in Excel 2013 VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint, excel-2013

I use VBA scripts in excel to generate PowerPoint slides for reporting.  However since we've upgraded to to Office 2013 my slides are generating in the new default of Widescreen (16:9) rather then Standard (4:3).

What is the Command in VBA to change the size of the PPT slides you are creating?  I assume it is a property of `PowerPoint.Application` but I couldn't figure it out.

Thanks, for the Help!!

-Colin

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833227/using-excel-vba-to-change-powerpoint-slide-size-late-binding). The answer was not accepted but it the question and answer should help.

Comment: Ah yes thank you.  I missed this the first time through.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeOnScreen
```

thanks